# displaying images based on euclidean(least) distance - python opencv

Tags: python, image-processing

i have been trying on displaying images based on the least distance(euclidean distance) but i am unable to find the result.

my code goes like:

```
import cv2
from collections import *
import CBIR as cb
import experiment as ex
from scipy.spatial import distance
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

result_list = list()
i = 0
a_list = list()
b_list = list()
a_list.append(ex.feature_matrix_ip)
while i < 50:
     b_list.append(cb.feature_matrix_db[i])
     dist = distance.euclidean(a_list,b_list[i])
     result_list.append(dist)
     result_list_sort = OrderedDict(sorted(enumerate(result_list),key=lambda x: x[0])).keys()
     i = i + 1 
result_list.sort()
res_list_sort = zip(result_list,result_list_sort)
images = cb.piclist
cv2.imshow('query image',ex.img)
plt.figure(2)
for i in xrange(6):
    plt.subplot(3,2,i+1),plt.imshow(images[i],'Spectral')
    plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

I have indexed the images in datasets.